# importing complex data from csv to mysql table

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, dbimport

I am trying to import data to a table. Basically its a MCQs. All my questions are having superscripts and subscripts, for example X<sup>2</sup> , and log<sub>5</sub><sup>2</sup>....

I have more than 2000 records, i have to import it. But after importing it comes in plain format, not taking powers. My DB is `MYSQL (UTF-8)`

Here is the example data

```
If log5 2, log5 (2x - 5) and   log 5(2x - 7/2)  are in AP , then x is equal to
```

after impoting it looks like above, but actually it should be

**If log<sub>5</sub> <sup>2</sup>, log5 (2<sup>x</sup> - 5) and   log 5(2<sup>x</sup> - 7/2)  are in AP , then x is equal to**

Somebody plz suggest me how to do it

Comment: Could you show an extract from the CSV?

Comment: Shouldn't your second and third `Log5` also have the `5` in subscript?

Comment: "<p>If log<sub>5</sub> <sup>2</sup>, log<sub>5</sub> (2<sup>x</sup> - 5) and&nbsp; log 5(2<sup>x</sup> - 7/2)&nbsp; are in AP , then x is equal to</p>
"this is i did from front end (ckeditor) and it stored like this and i exported to csv, it showed like this.
i do not have reputation to attach file. sorry

Comment: @BruceWayne: yes , it has.

Comment: How are you importing the CSV data to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix for the Subscripts:

```
Sub log_Script()
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim i&, k&
Dim myText$, findText$, curStr$


Set cel = Range("A1")
'myText = cel.Value

For i = 1 To Len(cel.Value)
    k = k + 1
    curStr = Mid(cel.Value, i, 1)
    If curStr <> " " Then
        findText = findText + curStr
    ElseIf curStr = " " Then
        findText = ""
    End If
    Debug.Print findText

    If findText = "log" Then
        If Mid(cel.Value, i + 1, 1) = " " Then
            With cel.Characters(Start:=k + 2, Length:=1).Font
                .Subscript = True
            End With
        Else
            With cel.Characters(Start:=k + 1, Length:=1).Font
                .Subscript = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This will go through a range (set currently to be `A1:A10`), and for each cell, it'll look for `log` then take the next number and make it subscript. (Note: This is assuming all logs will have base < 10, let me know if that's not necessarily the case).

I could probably make this better, if you can post a few rows or cells from your CSV so I can see what the formatting is exacly like. (Or screenshot a part of your data, that 'd work too).